# Scala list find and substraction

Tags: scala

my scala list as below `enter code here

```
    List((192.168.11.3,A,1413876302036,-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,12,0,0,Null0,UP,0,0,4294967295,other), (192.168.11.3,A,1413876302036,-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,8,0,0,C,DOWN,0,0,100000000,P),  (192.168.1.1,A,1413876001775,-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,12,0,0,E,UP,0,0,4294967295,other), (192.168.1.1,A,1413876001775,-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,8,0,0,F,DOWN,0,0,100000000,E))
```

Now I want following operation, in list third parameter are changed in above is  1413876302036 and 1413876001775. I want to subtracts this as below

```
 val sub = ((192.168.11.3,A,(1413876302036-1413876001775),-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,12,0,0,Null0,UP,0,0,4294967295,other),(192.168.1.1,A,(1413876001775-1413876001775),-,-,UP,,0.0,0.0,12,0,0,E,UP,0,0,4294967295,other))
```

how should this calculate in scala

Answer (score 0):

After 15 minutes of reading your question, I think I still don't understand it, but if I do here is an answer:

```
val list = List(("192.168.11.3",'A',1413876302036l,0,0,0), ("192.168.11.3",'A',1413876302036l,0,0,0),  
("192.168.1.1",'A',1413876001775l,0,0,0), ("192.168.1.1",'A',1413876001775l,0,0,0))

val newList = list map { _ match {
case (a,b,value,c,d,e) => (a,b,value-1413876001775l,c,d,e)
}}
```

I allowed myself to rewrite your example a little. Next time try to keep it simple and go with [SSCCE rules](http://sscce.org/)